How do you show that Cosmic Kite Problem is NP complete?
A "cosmic kite" of size k consists of a clique of k nodes with a path of k nodes that unfolds from one of the nodes in the clique.
Cosmic Kite as decision problem
Input: a graph G = (V, E) and a parameter k ∈ N.
Question: Does G contain a cosmic kite of cardinality at least k?
Show that Cosmic Kite is NP-complete

What have you tried?

Hint: Reduce from Clique. To every node, connect a path of $k$ vertices.
